# actualizar un subdocumento

Tags: nodejs, mongodb

Estoy intentando actualizar o agregar la propiedad estado en un sub documento , utilizando Robo 3T funciona bien , el problema es que con NodeJS no lo hace, esta es la sentencia que quiero escribir con NodeJS. Tanto el documento padre como el sub documento tienen su propio id.

La estructura de mi documento es así:

```
prescripcion = {
id_:
medicamentos [ { _id: } ],
...
}

// Por consola funciona bien
db.getCollection('prescripciones').update(
{ 'prescripcion._id': ObjectId('5cec1b5ec778991f5037d06e')}
{ 'medicamentos._id': ObjectId('5cec1b5ec778991f5037d06e')},
{ $set: { "medicamentos.$.estado" : 1 } }
)

// Código que utilizo en NodeJS

Prescripcion.findByIdAndUpdate(
{ "_id": '5cec1b5ec778991f5037d03b', 'medicamentos._id': '5cec1b5ec778991f5037d03c' },
{ "$set" : { 'medicamentos.$.Estado' : 1 } } , { new: true }, (err, model) => {
  if (err) console.log('err: ' + err);
  else
    console.log('updated');
});

res.send('1');
});
```

De antemano muchas gracias por quien pueda orientarme!!!

Comment: Hola, en tu código de Node pone `medicamentos.$.Estado` y en el código que te funciona en minúsculas `medicamentos.$.estado`. Puede que eso te este penalizando.

Comment: Sigo con el mismo inconveniente a pesar del cambio que sugieres... @pla

Comment: Ok, podrías añadir un documento como ejemplo para que pueda probar?

Comment: ¿Te arroja algún tipo de error?